# Converting C functions in Delphi 10 Seattle

Tags: c, delphi, type-conversion

I'm trying to convert [API SendAnywhere header file](https://github.com/estmob/SendAnywhere-Desktop-SDK/blob/master/SDK/include/internal/paprika.h) from C to Delphi 10 code for Windows.

Using [presented table of Embarcadero](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Seattle/en/Delphi_to_C%2B%2B_types_mapping) I successfully convert some of the functions:

```
typedef void* PaprikaTask;
typedef void* PaprikaAuthToken;

__declspec(dllexport) void paprika_set_apikey(const char* key);
__declspec(dllexport) PaprikaAuthToken paprika_auth_create();
__declspec(dllexport) PaprikaAuthToken paprika_auth_create_with_deviceid(const char* id, const char* password);
__declspec(dllexport) void paprika_auth_close(PaprikaAuthToken auth);
__declspec(dllexport) bool paprika_is_running(PaprikaTask task);
__declspec(dllexport) PaprikaTask paprika_create_download(const wchar_t* key, const wchar_t* destDirPath);
__declspec(dllexport) void paprika_start(PaprikaTask task);
```

This is my conversion:

```
PaprikaAuthToken = Pointer;
PaprikaTask = Pointer;

procedure paprika_set_apikey(const key: PChar); cdecl; external 'sendanywhere.dll';
function paprika_auth_create: PaprikaAuthToken; cdecl; external 'sendanywhere.dll';
function paprika_auth_create_with_deviceid(const id: PAnsiChar; const password: PAnsiChar): PaprikaAuthToken; cdecl; external 'sendanywhere.dll';
procedure paprika_auth_close(auth: PaprikaAuthToken); cdecl; external 'sendanywhere.dll';
function paprika_is_running(task: PaprikaTask): Boolean; cdecl; external 'sendanywhere.dll';
function paprika_create_download(const key: PWideChar; const destDirPath: PWideChar): PaprikaTask; cdecl; external 'sendanywhere.dll';
procedure paprika_start(task: PaprikaTask); cdecl; external 'sendanywhere.dll';
```

Example from SendAnywhere uses these functions as follows:

```
PaprikaTask pTask;
PaprikaAuthToken gToken;

paprika_set_apikey("YOUR_API_KEY");
gToken = paprika_auth_create();
pTask = paprika_create_download(L"KEY", L"/tmp"); 
paprika_set_auth(pTask, gToken);
paprika_start(pTask);
```

This is how I interpreted the proper code:

```
var
FAuthToken: PaprikaAuthToken;
FOption: PaprikaOption;   

paprika_set_apikey(PChar('my_correct_api_key'));
FAuthToken = paprika_auth_create();
// backslash for windows
FTask := paprika_create_download(PWideChar('correct_key'), PWideChar('\tmp')); //directory exists
paprika_set_auth(FTask, FAuthToken);
paprika_start(FTask);
```

I checked the work of the task by function **paprika_is_running**. It returns **FALSE** before calling **paprika_start_function**. It begins to return **TRUE** after calling **paprika_start_function** but after 1-2 seconds (regardless of the size of the transferring file) it returns **FALSE**.
This means that the function is working, but it seems that the problem is in the arguments.

*Please tell me where I am going wrong?*

Maybe there is an incorrect conversion from **string** to **TWideChar**.
Or the path of the directory is passed incorrectly, for example and used an incorrect slash. I've tried different paths:

('C:/', 'C:\', 'C:', 'file://C:', 'file://C:/', '/', '\', '')

*What is incorrect? Help please. I need your assistance.*

Comment: FWIW, I recommend reading my article about such conversions, [Pitfalls of Converting](http://rvelthuis.de/articles/articles-convert.html). It handles these things in depth.

Comment: Thank you! Awesome article! There're many usefull things. Why didn't Google Search find it for me earlier...

Answer (score 1):

```
procedure paprika_set_apikey(const key: PChar); cdecl; external 'sendanywhere.dll';
```

This is wrong. `PChar` is an alias to `PWideChar`. The type should be `PAnsiChar`.

As an aside you don't need the `PAnsiChar` or `PWideChar` casts when passing literals. Remove them to simplify the code.

Further, your use of `const` in parameters has a different meaning from that in the C++ code, and is in any case meaningless in an external declaration. I personally would remove those modifiers and pass the pointers as plain value params.

Comment: Thnx! I modified 1st function as:

`procedure paprika_set_apikey(key: PAnsiChar); cdecl; external 'sendanywhere.dll';`

And what do you meen when advice me to remove `PAnsiChar` and `PWideChar`? Could you give an example at this function:

`PaprikaTask paprika_create_download(const wchar_t* key, const wchar_t* destDirPath);`
Will it look like `function paprika_create_download(key: Pointer; destDirPath: Pointer): PaprikaTask;`?

Comment: I didn't say that. I said "you don't need the `PAnsiChar` or `PWideChar` casts". Do you know what a cast is? If not, you should look it up. I mean that you don't need to write `PWideChar('correct_key')` and can write `'correct_key'`

Comment: So that function can be `function paprika_create_download(key: PWideChar; destDirPath: PWideChar): PaprikaTask; cdecl; external 'sendanywhere.dll';` since the `const` serves no purpose, and when you call it you don't need to cast the literals. Do you know what a literal is? Again, if you don't you need to know. This terminology is critical.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I know what it's mean. It was just my bad english interpretation. Sorry.